# How to hide certain lines from modelsummary of regression analysis

Tags: r, regression, modelsummary

I have a regression output as follows:

```
regression1 <- lm(cnt ~ temperature + weathersit + humidity + windvelocity, data=captialbikedata)
modelsummary(regression1)
```

I am using modelsummary in order to display it in a table in markdown.

I want to hide the following rows of the regression output:

- AIC
- BIC
- Log.Lik.
- F

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gof_omit` allows you to omit goodness-of-fit statistics, which is what `modelsummary` calls all the statistics reported in the bottom section of the table.

This argument accepts "regular expressions", which allows you to use partial matches and a variety of other tricks. One nice trick is to use the vertical bar (`|`, meaning "OR") to say that you want to omit *any one of* many patterns.

```r
library("modelsummary")

mod <- lm(hp ~ mpg, mtcars)
modelsummary(mod, gof_omit = "AIC|BIC|Log|F")
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 324.082 |
|  | (27.433) |
| mpg | -8.830 |
|  | (1.310) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.602 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.589 |

In addition, you can omit coefficients using the `coef_omit` argument in a similar way. Finally, you can omit the standard errors in parentheses by setting `statistic=NULL`.